# How to align menu to be on the same line

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

[image]

How do I align this menu properly? I have tried using inline-block for the li tag but that didn't align this.

Here's the current code, please help with ideas

```
            <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md">
                <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'index' %}">Active Listings</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a href="#">Category</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a href="#">Sell</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                   <div>
                        {% if user.is_authenticated %}
                            welcome, <strong>{{ user.username }}</strong>.
                        {% else %}
                            Not signed in.
                        {% endif %}
                    
                    </div>
                    
                        {% if user.is_authenticated %}
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'logout' %}">Log Out</a>
                        </li>
                        {% else %}
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'login' %}">Log In</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'register' %}">Register</a>
                        </li>
                        {% endif %}
                </ul>
            </nav>
```

Comment: Fix your broken HTML first. UL can not contain DIV as a child.

Comment: AND be consistent.  If you are going to use class="nav-link" for anchors inside your li's then do that for all of them.

Comment: There's no good reason to use ul/li when you can just use `<nav class="nav">...</nav>`

Comment: @CBroe, thanks, I've updated the HTML and changed the div to an li. I did not know that you cannot have a div within a ul. Thank you

Comment: @gview, thank you, I did not realize that I omitted the nav-link and this helped in aligning my left menu. The Not Signed In is still not aligned but I would try to figure this out. Thank you

Comment: See @CBroe's message.  You can't inject a div in the middle of a ul.  A ul can only have child li inside it.  As I mentioned, you don't need to use a ul at all. Just use the nav tag, and nest your links in the nav.  You'll have less issue with your twig logic.  For your name, instead of using a div around the text you want to present, use a span.

Answer (score -1):

Try to add display flex and align items center. this will 100% solve your problem

```
  ul {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
 }
```

Comment: Question is about bootstrap4.

Comment: The bootstrap styles are already handling that, so yeah no, that's not the way to do it with bootstrap.

Comment: The issue the guy has is that he left out a style in one link.  Not that he didn't redundantly make a flexbox style which is already being done by the bootstrap nav style.